# Merge two nested sets into rows

Tags: sql, nested-sets

I'm given a nested set database which has the following reduced structure:

Bus its root table (**B**)

| CL | CR | SL | SR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 12 |

Compound table which represents levels of hierarchy with each level having different attributes (**C**)
Level 1 (**C1**)

| CL | CR | SL | SR | C5 | C6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 12 | NULL | test |

Level 2 (**C2a**)

| CL | CR | SL | SR | C5 | C6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 12 | foo | NULL |

and (**C2b**)

| CL | CR | SL | SR | C5 | C6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 12 | bar | NULL |

Lastly S containing signals where S1 is it’s id.

| S1 | S2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0xFA |
| .. | .. |
| 11 | 0x10 |

Then comes the tricky part:
I need to create a list of the 10 S table items with the complete path and hierarchical values up the tree.

So it would result in a list with values that look something like this

| S | C | .. | C | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S2-values | C2a-values | .. | C1-values | R |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| S11-values | C2a-values | .. | C1-values | R |
| S2-values | C2b-values | .. | C1-values | R |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| S11-values | C2b-values | .. | C1-values | R |

Any suggestion to loosen the knot in my brain is helpful.

What I tried so far is the following, which does not seem to work as it just crashes the machine:

```
select
    *
from
    signal s,
    compound c 
join (
    select
        bus.short_name,
        cBase.dtype,
        cBase.value,
        cPdu.relative_bit_position,
        cPdu.bit_length,
        cPdu.left_signal,
        cPdu.right_signal,
        cSwp.switch_code
    from
        compound as cbase
    left join compound as cPdu on
        cPdu.dtype = 'P'
        and cBase.left_compound < cPdu.left_compound
        and cBase.right_compound > cPdu.right_compound
    left join compound as cswp on
        cSwp.dtype = 'SWP'
        and cBase.left_compound < cSwp.left_compound
        and cBase.right_compound > cSwp.right_compound
    left join bus as bus on
        bus.left_compound < cBase.left_compound
        and bus.right_compound > cBase.right_compound
    where
        cBase.dType = 'CF') as res on s.id between res.left_signal and res.right_signal
```

In the above code I restricted the depth of the categories to 3 (cBase, cPdu, cSwp).
What I need is a generalized approach that can handle all depths.

Comment: Put an empty row before each table, and they will look much better.

Comment: i haven't the slightest idea, what you are tryong to achieve, or what your endresult would be S1 for example what is that when it is at home

Comment: @nbk S1 ist a row of table S representing signals. C are hierarchical categories and the root R has the information of its leftest and riggtest category as well as underlying signal. The goal is a list of each signal with all possible categories as well as the root

Comment: What are '10 S items from another table' - why is that table not in your question? How is it related to other tables?

Comment: @June7 added signal table

Comment: Table and field names used in query do not correspond to names in sample tables. Still don't understand table relationships.

Comment: We can't understand your model the added query has no representation in the tables presented a erp to understand the relation between all tables proper names help to clear things up